# Query Running Speed Different on Web Application and Database Management Tool

Tags: mysql

I am developing a web application using Django, during the development process. I found out something weird and I can't find the answer for it.

I was using Sqlalchemy in Django to construct a complex query, it was completed within 1 second, but when I run the query on SQLYog (Database Management Tool), it took about 40 seconds to complete.

The situation often happens when there is a `like` operator on a text column.

I am pretty sure that both query run is the same because I output the query log in Sqlalchemy then run in SQLYog.

Comment: *it was completed within 1 second ... it took about 40 seconds to complete.* What time do you speak about? Clear execution time (by MySQL statistic) or a time between the execution starting and the result output to the screen?

Comment: @Akina is the time between the execution starting and the result output to the screen

Comment: *when I run the query on SQLYog (Database Management Tool), it took about 40 seconds* 1 sec for MySQL and 39 sec for to print the output on the screen...